# Java regex matching each occurence separately

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have this regex:

```
<a href(.*foo.bar.*)a>
```

For this string, it gives me only 1 match, but I need it to give 3 matches.

```
<a href="https://foo.bar/1">First</a> RANDOM TEXT COULD BE HERE <a href="https://foo.bar/2">Second</a> RANDOM TEXT COULD BE HERE <a href="https://foo.bar/3">Third</a>
```

So each `a href` should be individual.

How could I accomplish this?

EDIT:

This code searches for matches:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href(.*foo.bar.*)a>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that searches for matches please?

Comment: @JREN : Added the searcher code

Comment: [*Parsing HTML is a solved problem. You do not need to solve it. You just need to be lazy.*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: If you're working with html, you should use a html parser...  [stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to:

```
<a href(.*?foo\.bar.*?)a>
```

It removes the greediness. And real dots should be escaped to `\.`.

Comment: Problem occured, the start seems to be greedy also. The regex will match this whole part, but should only take the ending. `<a href="https://anyURL.com"> TEST TEST</a><a href="https://foo.bar/86917">MY REAL PAGE</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*`. The greedy quantifier matches characters as many as possible, while the reluctant quantifier matches the least number of characters in a single find operation.

Besides, use `foo\.bar` if you intend to match a literal text of "foo.bar".

Comment: Thanks, like the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you:

```
int noOfTimefoundString = 0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"https://foo.bar");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
  matches.add(matcher.group());
  noOfTimefoundString++;
}
Iterator matchesItr = matches.iterator();
while(matchesItr.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(matchesItr.next());
}
System.out.println("No. of times search string found = "+noOfTimefoundString);
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to store them to somewhere. I need the full urls with tags.